# visual C++ send text to cursor

Tags: c++, cursor, nfc

I am using a NFC reader to read the UID of a M1 card and I would like to insert this UID string to anywhere the cursor currently is.
e.g. in the url box, in notepad, (just like a "barcode" reader input device, but with NFC UID this time)

I have implemented the function for reading the UID, and now I would like to do my second part - to insert the UID to anywhere the cursor is.

I am using Visual C++, any idea?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet / have any leads at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simulate a keypress, you can add input events:

```
INPUT inp;

inp.ki.dwFlags = 0;
inp.ki.wVk = 'A';
inp.ki.wScan = 0;
inp.ki.time = 0;
inp.ki.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
inp.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

SendInput(1, (LPINPUT) &inp, sizeof(inp));

inp.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

SendInput(1, (LPINPUT) &inp, sizeof(inp));
```

That sends a key-down, followed by a key-up for the 'A' key. You can submit an array of those structures in a single call, I've omitted that for clarity. Note also that the key is *not* ascii, but a VK code. It just so happens that the alpha keys are represented by their upper-case value.

Obviously if the user happens not to have the cursor somewhere that they *want* characters to be entered, bad/unexpected things may happen.

Answer (score 0):

Place the text on the clipboard. Then the user can paste it. Leave the user in control, don't foul up what the user's doing.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
But actually I am working on a project: when user place their card onto the reader, I have to read the UID and pass it to the text box of a webpage for further processing. The system will be dedicated for sole purpose.

Comment: otoh., if you really really would like to foul up things for the user, creating a situation where mishaps will happen, then check out e.g. `WM_PASTE`. not guaranteeing it will work (i can't remember whether it's a notification or an action). but thereabouts.